# Is there anything special about single vowel words?

Tags: meaning, etymology, poetry, vowels

I'm not sure if this is a useful question or not. But I was surprised to notice まさか (masaka) was using a single vowel (a) for the whole word. The surprise came from the connection to "bakana" (バカな) which apparently is two words, so never mind that.

I set out to discover more of these single-vowel words in Japanese, but I don't really know Japanese or how to search for such things. So I found a list of words and analyzed them here https://colab.research.google.com/drive/194vb5Ajw4mMlUcb1HqF4YF2aP1LjeVlS

This prints out:

```
Found 22 single column words
あなた
うつむく
からだ
くぐる
さまざま
せめて
そのもの
そもそも
そろそろ
だから
つくる
つづく
ところ
どころ
なかなか
ながら
ふつう
まさか
もともと
ものの
よほど
わざわざ
```

Which I guess is a cute tongue-twister. The question is - does this class of words have a name? Are these words more poetic in a way? Are there other, longer, words like this that I missed?

Comment: まあ、わからなかったんだがなぁ。 ← You can even get whole sentences.  :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Does this class of words have a name?

I don't think so. Do words like "banana" and "indivisibility" have a special name in English?

> Are these words more poetic in a way?

As wordplay, a poem that contains many such words may exist somewhere, but it's not popular at all.

> Are there other, longer, words like this that I missed?

Japanese has only 5 vowels, so there are tons of such examples. The ["top 3000 words" list you used](http://www.offbeatband.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/11/Japanese-Word-Frequency-List-1-3000.txt) contain many words in kanji or katakana, which means you have already missed many simple words with only one vowel, such as 魚 (sa-ka-na, "fish"), 知識 (chi-shi-ki, "knowledge") and 男 (o-to-ko, "man"). If you don't know about kanji, please learn about the [Japanese writing system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_writing_system) first. They are not particularly difficult to pronounce to me, either.

In Japanese, it's not that difficult to construct a long sentence that contains only one vowel. I came up with this (28 o's):

> 大園桃子の母校の曽於高校の校章を覆おう。
> O-o-zo-no Mo-mo-ko-no bo-ko-o no So-o ko-o-ko-o no ko-o-sho-o o o-o-o-o.
> "Let's cover the emblem of Sō High School, [Momoko Ōzono](http://stage48.net/wiki/index.php/Ozono_Momoko)'s alma mater."

---

**EDIT:** I made a longer example for fun (53 a's)

> 雨傘が無かったから差さなかったら、朝から体が硬かったが、まあ戦ったら勝ったから、あからさまな差は無かったかな。
>
> A-ma-ga-sa ga na-ka-tta ka-ra sa-sa-na-ka-tta-ra, a-sa ka-ra ka-ra-da ga ka-ta-ka-tta ga, ma-a ta-ta-ka-tta-ra ka-tta ka-ra, a-ka-ra-sa-ma-na sa wa na-ka-tta ka-na.
>
> "I did not use an umbrella because I did not have one, so my body was stiff since this morning, but, well, I still fought and won, so I guess that made no obvious difference."

Comment: Love the long o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o example.  :D

Comment: `「刀」か、片仮名なら「カ」かな。` *Ka-ta-na ka, ka-ta-ka-na na-ra ka ka-na*. "This letter is 刀 (katana), or if it's katakana, it's カ (ka), perhaps?"

Comment: — Good stuff!  

Comment: I suspect such a feat is impossible in English. Thank you!

Comment: @ubershmekel or not...? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Univocalic

Comment: @broccoliforest あるんかーいｗ (というか昔見たことある気もしてきました)

Comment: @naruto わからなかったがたまたまあったから貼ったｗ (あx17)